# Show only certain tags when using gitk?

Tags: linux, git, gitk

Every commit in our repository has a tag associated with it. There are a lot of tags on a branch that have "B7" in the name. Can I run `gitk` and exclude all of these "B7" tags? Conversely, how can I run `gitk` and show only the commits that **do** have "B7" in them?

I'm tired of doing `gitk --all` and getting a bunch of extra fluff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It occurred to me halfway through writing this that maybe you want the commits displayed, but just want some of those commits not to show tags that point to them.  This answers instead the question "how do I see all commits reachable from some or all branches, but not commits reachable from certain tags that are not also reachable from those branches?".

---

`gitk` takes the same options as `git-rev-list`, for selecting commits to display.  Hence, instead of `--all` you can provide `--branches` and/or `--tags`, both of which accept "pattern" arguments.

Unfortunately, the pattern arguments are shell glob style patterns, where it's very easy to include those containing `B7` (`*B7*` will do the trick) but difficult to exclude those that contain something that has `B7` embedded at an arbitrary position within it.  If the `B7` is at the *beginning* or *end* of the name it's less difficult, though still a bit messy: `--tags="[AC-Za-z]*" --tags="B[A-Za-z0-689]*"`, for instance, is probably good enough to match two-or-more character tags that do not begin with `B7` (add `--tags="?"` to include one-character tags as well).

(The double quotes here are to prevent the shell from attempting to expand the shell-style globs, although in most shell variants, as long as there are no files [in the current directory] whose names start with `--tags=`, you can get away without them.)

For full flexibility, you can use `git for-each-ref` or `git show-ref` to enumerate references, piping the ref names through something like `grep -v` to include or exclude arbitrary regular expressions, and delivering the result as arguments to `gitk`.  For instance, to see all commits on all branches, plus commits on

```
gitk --branches $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/tags/ |
    grep -v B7)
```

(not actually tested, but simple and should work, assuming `sh` or `bash` shells).

(For `csh` or `tcsh`, put everything on one line, or use backslash before newlines; and replace `cmd ... $(subcmd ...)` with `` cmd ... `subcmd ...` ``.  The backquote version is generally inferior syntactically as it cannot be nested, but it will do in this case.  Even though I use tcsh as an interactive shell, I switch to sh for scripting.)

Comment: You have some unmatched parenthesis there... I tried to fix but I'm still getting an 'illegal variable name' error. Can you amend your answer?

Comment: The close parenthesis for the `$(` is on the 2nd line.  Some shell variants will complain (and some don't even have `$(` as a syntax...) but `sh` and `bash` should be fine with it.  If not, put it all on one line and use backquotes instead of $(...) (this should work for csh / tcsh; no idea about dash and zsh).

Comment: Thanks for the fix and explanation. This works and does what I want!